# Fast calculations of the Pareto front in R

Tags: r, performance, if-statement

So I am trying to calculate the Pareto front (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency) in `R` and am able to do it, however, I am not able to do it efficiently.  In particular as the number of pairs of points increases, the computations slow down considerably.

So in general, what I want to do is check for all non-dominated (or dominated) pairs. Now the way I have been doing this is to find all such pair of points such that **x<sub>i</sub> > X**
 and **y<sub>i</sub> > Y** where **(x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>)** are a single pair and **X** and **Y** represent all points **x** and **y**.  Now, this part works very fast and is easy to implement, however, there is the additional possibility that multiple **x** values may be the same but they will have different **y** values so in that case I want to be able to identify the **x** value that has the lowest **y** value (and vise versa for points that have identical **y** values but different **x** values).

To illustrate this point here is a picture from Wikipedia:

[image]

so basically I want to be able to identify all points that lie on the red line.

Here is my code that does work but is very inefficient for large datasets:

```
#Example Data that actually runs quickly
x = runif(10000)
y = runif(10000)

pareto = 1:length(x)

for(i in 1:length(x)){
    cond1 = y[i]!=min(y[which(x==x[i])])
    cond2 = x[i]!=min(x[which(y==y[i])])
    for(n in 1:length(x)){
        if((x[i]>x[n]  &  y[i]>y[n]) | (x[i]==x[n] & cond1) | (y[i]==y[n] & cond2)){
            pareto[i] = NA
            break
        }
    }
}
#All points not on the red line should be marks as NA in the pareto variable
```

The slow down definitely comes from calculating the points where `(x[i]==x[n] & cond1) | (y[i]==y[n] & cond2)` but I cannot find a way around it or a better Boolean expression to capture everything that I want. any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the [rPref package](http://www.p-roocks.de/rpref) I did a efficient implementation of Pareto frontiers (Skylines) in C++.

Answer (score 7):

Following @BrodieG

```
system.time( {
    d = data.frame(x,y)
    D = d[order(d$x,d$y,decreasing=FALSE),]
    front = D[which(!duplicated(cummin(D$y))),]
} )

   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.02
```

which is 0.86/0.02 = 43 times faster!

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: new version:

```
system.time( {
  pareto.2 <- logical(length(x))
  x.sort <- sort(x)
  y.sort <- y[order(x)]
  y.min <- max(y)
  for(i in 1:length(x.sort)) {
    if(pareto.2[i] <- y.sort[i] <= y.min) y.min <- y.sort[i]
  }    
} )
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.036   0.000   0.035
```

---

OLD VERSION:

This is about 6x faster on my system.  You can probably do better with a better algorithm, as well as with `Rcpp`, but this was straightforward.  The trick here is to sort by `x`, which then allows you to limit your check to making sure that all prior values of `x` must have greater values of `y` to ensure that point is on the frontier.

```
system.time( {
  pareto.2 <- logical(length(x))
  x.sort <- sort(x)
  y.sort <- y[order(x)]
  for(i in 1:length(x.sort)) {
    pareto.2[i] <- all(y.sort[1:i] >= y.sort[i])
  }    
} )
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.86    0.00    0.88
```

The original:

```
pareto = 1:length(x)
system.time(
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    cond1 = y[i]!= min(y[which(x==x[i])])
    cond2 = x[i]!= min(x[which(y==y[i])])
    for(n in 1:length(x)){
      if((x[i]>x[n]  &  y[i]>y[n]) | (x[i]==x[n] & cond1) | (y[i]==y[n] & cond2)){
        pareto[i] = NA
        break
      }
    }
  }  
)
# user  system elapsed 
# 5.32    0.00    5.33
```

And showing the two methods produce the same result (a bit tricky because I need to re-order pareto.2 to the original order of `x`):

```
all.equal(pareto.2[match(1:length(x), order(x))], !is.na(pareto))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I actually found an even faster way to solve this from someone else's post although I like the readiability of for loops.  To see the answer check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296795/counting-points-in-r where I am actually now asking another question.

Comment: @StatMan, see new version in the answer.  Seems comparable to the other one you found.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to share with you my solution as a function. It's been tested and works pretty good for N Pareto-fronts. Set to `fronts = Inf` to calculate all fronts.

```
pareto_front <- function(x, y, fronts = 1, sort = TRUE) {
  stopifnot(length(x) == length(y))
  d <- data.frame(x, y)
  Dtemp <- D <- d[order(d$x, d$y, decreasing = FALSE), ]
  df <- data.frame()
  i <- 1
  while (nrow(Dtemp) >= 1 & i <= max(fronts)) {
    these <- Dtemp[which(!duplicated(cummin(Dtemp$y))), ]
    these$pareto_front <- i
    df <- rbind(df, these)
    Dtemp <- Dtemp[!row.names(Dtemp) %in% row.names(these), ]
    i <- i + 1
  }
  ret <- merge(x = d, y = df, by = c("x", "y"), all.x = TRUE, sort = sort)
  return(ret)
}
```

[image]