# Counting points in R

Tags: r

Suppose I the create the following picture from 40 (x,y) pairs.

[image]

Now given additional points, in black, I would like to be able to count how many points fall inside the blue area versus how many fall outside (in a very efficient way since I will be doing this a large number of times inside a costly loop).  To illustrate what I am looking for consider the next figure:

[image]

So as you can see from the above figure, I would like to be able to say that there are 3 black points outside the blue area and 7 black points inside the blue area.

Here is the code that I wrote for accomplishing the above figures.

```
#x,y data
x = rnorm(40)
y = rnorm(40)

#Calculates the green points
d = data.frame(x,y)
D = d[order(d$x,d$y,decreasing=FALSE),]
front = D[which(!duplicated(cummin(D$y))),]

plot(x,y,pch=21,bg="red",xlim=c(-5,5),ylim=c(-5,5))
points(front$x,front$y,pch=21,bg="green")

rect(front$x,front$y,max(x)+100000,max(y)+100000,col="lightblue",border=NA)

points(x,y,bg="red",pch=21)
points(front$x,front$y,bg="green",pch=21)

#Additional 10 black points
w = rnorm(10,3)
z = rnorm(10,-1)
points(w,z,pch=19,col="black")
```

I am actually able to figure out how many points do fall in the blue area, however, I have to do this calculation inside of a loop which is extremely slow.  I would like to be able to do the calculation outside of a loop to speed up my computations.

Comment: So how are you currently doing it? Posting your current method might enable us to give you some pointers about how to speed up the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
blacks <- cbind.data.frame(x=w, y=z)
sum(apply(blacks, 1, function(black) { 
  !any(front$y < black['y'] & front$x < black['x'])
}))
```

Comment: Change my code to the following and you will see that your code doesn't work always:  set.seed(44); w = rnorm(10,-2);
z = rnorm(10,-4); is a counterexample

Comment: now it works!  Thanks!  Lastly, I am not super savvy about what your function is doing.  Do you think you can elaborate on it?

Comment: I try: The `apply` takes every `blacks` pixel coordinate one after another. For each one, it checks if it is greater (`<`) than `any` of the `front` coords. So `TRUE` means beeing on the blue. However, we want `TRUE` for beeing on the white - `!` reverses this (TRUE gets FALSE and vice versa). Finally, we take the `sum` of all the TRUEs (=1s). Et voila.

Comment: I delete the 1st try to clean it up.

Comment: Awesome, sorry to ask, but what if I wanted to add the restriction that no x value be larger than say 2?

Comment: By my last comment I mean count all the points that are in the white and are also have an x value < 2?

Comment: Then it would be `(!any(front$y < black['y'] & front$x < black['x'])) & black['x'] < 2`

Comment: `>2` would mean: only x values greater than 2.

Comment: Your right sorry.  The difference was I had `| black['x'] > 2` instead of `&`

Comment: Also does your method work if points are the same? As in if the green point x value and the black points x value were the same?