# Fast calculation of Pareto front in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of points in a 3D space, from which I need to find the Pareto frontier. Speed of execution is very important here, and time increases very fast as I add points to test.

The set of points looks like this:

```
[[0.3296170319979843, 0.0, 0.44472108843537406], [0.3296170319979843,0.0, 0.44472108843537406], [0.32920760896951373, 0.0, 0.4440408163265306], [0.32920760896951373, 0.0, 0.4440408163265306], [0.33815192743764166, 0.0, 0.44356462585034007]]
```

Right now, I'm using this algorithm:

```
def dominates(row, candidateRow):
    return sum([row[x] >= candidateRow[x] for x in range(len(row))]) == len(row) 

def simple_cull(inputPoints, dominates):
    paretoPoints = set()
    candidateRowNr = 0
    dominatedPoints = set()
    while True:
        candidateRow = inputPoints[candidateRowNr]
        inputPoints.remove(candidateRow)
        rowNr = 0
        nonDominated = True
        while len(inputPoints) != 0 and rowNr < len(inputPoints):
            row = inputPoints[rowNr]
            if dominates(candidateRow, row):
                # If it is worse on all features remove the row from the array
                inputPoints.remove(row)
                dominatedPoints.add(tuple(row))
            elif dominates(row, candidateRow):
                nonDominated = False
                dominatedPoints.add(tuple(candidateRow))
                rowNr += 1
            else:
                rowNr += 1

        if nonDominated:
            # add the non-dominated point to the Pareto frontier
            paretoPoints.add(tuple(candidateRow))

        if len(inputPoints) == 0:
            break
    return paretoPoints, dominatedPoints
```

Found here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578287-multidimensional-pareto-front/

What's the fastest way to find the set of non-dominated solutions in an ensemble of solutions? Or, in short, can Python do better than this algorithm?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you're worried about actual speed, you definitely want to use numpy (as the clever algorithmic tweaks probably have way less effect than the gains to be had from using array operations).  Here are three solutions that all compute the same function.  The `is_pareto_efficient_dumb` solution is slower in most situations but becomes faster as the number of costs increases, the `is_pareto_efficient_simple` solution is much more efficient than the dumb solution for many points, and the final `is_pareto_efficient` function is less readable but the fastest (so all are Pareto Efficient!).

```
import numpy as np


# Very slow for many datapoints.  Fastest for many costs, most readable
def is_pareto_efficient_dumb(costs):
    """
    Find the pareto-efficient points
    :param costs: An (n_points, n_costs) array
    :return: A (n_points, ) boolean array, indicating whether each point is Pareto efficient
    """
    is_efficient = np.ones(costs.shape[0], dtype = bool)
    for i, c in enumerate(costs):
        is_efficient[i] = np.all(np.any(costs[:i]>c, axis=1)) and np.all(np.any(costs[i+1:]>c, axis=1))
    return is_efficient


# Fairly fast for many datapoints, less fast for many costs, somewhat readable
def is_pareto_efficient_simple(costs):
    """
    Find the pareto-efficient points
    :param costs: An (n_points, n_costs) array
    :return: A (n_points, ) boolean array, indicating whether each point is Pareto efficient
    """
    is_efficient = np.ones(costs.shape[0], dtype = bool)
    for i, c in enumerate(costs):
        if is_efficient[i]:
            is_efficient[is_efficient] = np.any(costs[is_efficient]<c, axis=1)  # Keep any point with a lower cost
            is_efficient[i] = True  # And keep self
    return is_efficient


# Faster than is_pareto_efficient_simple, but less readable.
def is_pareto_efficient(costs, return_mask = True):
    """
    Find the pareto-efficient points
    :param costs: An (n_points, n_costs) array
    :param return_mask: True to return a mask
    :return: An array of indices of pareto-efficient points.
        If return_mask is True, this will be an (n_points, ) boolean array
        Otherwise it will be a (n_efficient_points, ) integer array of indices.
    """
    is_efficient = np.arange(costs.shape[0])
    n_points = costs.shape[0]
    next_point_index = 0  # Next index in the is_efficient array to search for
    while next_point_index<len(costs):
        nondominated_point_mask = np.any(costs<costs[next_point_index], axis=1)
        nondominated_point_mask[next_point_index] = True
        is_efficient = is_efficient[nondominated_point_mask]  # Remove dominated points
        costs = costs[nondominated_point_mask]
        next_point_index = np.sum(nondominated_point_mask[:next_point_index])+1
    if return_mask:
        is_efficient_mask = np.zeros(n_points, dtype = bool)
        is_efficient_mask[is_efficient] = True
        return is_efficient_mask
    else:
        return is_efficient
```

Profiling tests (using points drawn from a Normal distribution):

With 10,000 samples, 2 costs:

```
is_pareto_efficient_dumb: Elapsed time is 1.586s
is_pareto_efficient_simple: Elapsed time is 0.009653s
is_pareto_efficient: Elapsed time is 0.005479s
```

With 1,000,000 samples, 2 costs:

```
is_pareto_efficient_dumb: Really, really, slow
is_pareto_efficient_simple: Elapsed time is 1.174s
is_pareto_efficient: Elapsed time is 0.4033s
```

With 10,000 samples, 15 costs:

```
is_pareto_efficient_dumb: Elapsed time is 4.019s
is_pareto_efficient_simple: Elapsed time is 6.466s
is_pareto_efficient: Elapsed time is 6.41s
```

Note that if efficiency is a concern you can gain maybe a further 2x or so speedup by reordering your data beforehand, see [here](https://github.com/QUVA-Lab/artemis/blob/peter/artemis/general/pareto_efficiency.py).

Comment: Wow, I missed it, thank you Peter! I"m not quite sure I get the cost array though, could you provide a short example? Thanks once again, this looks fantastic.

Comment: Cost array is just a 2-d array where cost[i, j] is the j'th cost of the i'th data point.  I think it's the same as your inputPoints array.  You can see the [tests here](https://github.com/QUVA-Lab/artemis/blob/master/artemis/general/test_pareto_efficiency.py), which demonstrate its use.

Comment: I tested it with a simple example and the first two functions do not return the pareto front.
The example:
`numpy.array([[1,2], [3,4], [2,1], [1,1]])`

It returns the following:
`[ True False  True  True]`
But it should return by the definition of pareto front this:
`[ False False  False  True]`

Comment: A fix for the def is_pareto_efficient(costs): would look like this (replace the mentioned lines):

`is_efficient[is_efficient] = np.any(costs[is_efficient]<c, axis=1)  # Remove dominated points`
`is_efficient[i] = True`

Comment: Thanks for finding that @hyperionb - I hadn't tested on integers.  I updated the functions with your fix.

Comment: If you have nan values in your costs you can change the initial assignment of `is_efficient` to `is_efficient = np.all(np.logical_not(np.isnan(costs)), axis=1)` in the first two functions.

Comment: Can you share the reference to scientific papers about these algorithms?

Comment: Hello, dear @Peter . Why do we need the n_costs? Why the n_points only are not enough?

Comment: I do not understand the question

Comment: Dear @Peter. Thanks for this fantastic answer. If this is published in a journal, please let us know the citation.

Comment: @Peter The costs in my case in def is_pareto_efficient_dumb(costs): is a  numpy array of points with each point having three dimensions i.e. it has three objective function values. Its a minimization problem. I used the first set of code solving. However, when I run the code I get no output and when I read is_efficient it says "is_efficient" is not defined.

Comment: I suspect you're not calling the function.  You need to go `is_efficient = is_pareto_efficient(my_costs_array)`

Comment: @Peter If I am using "is_pareto_efficient_dumb" how can I use the Boolean array result for plotting?

Comment: you can select efficient points with `my_efficient_costs_array = my_costs_array[is_efficient]` and plot those.

Answer (score 17):

#### Updated Aug 2019

Here is another simple implementation that is pretty fast for modest dimensions. Input points are assumed to be unique.

```
def keep_efficient(pts):
    'returns Pareto efficient row subset of pts'
    # sort points by decreasing sum of coordinates
    pts = pts[pts.sum(1).argsort()[::-1]]
    # initialize a boolean mask for undominated points
    # to avoid creating copies each iteration
    undominated = np.ones(pts.shape[0], dtype=bool)
    for i in range(pts.shape[0]):
        # process each point in turn
        n = pts.shape[0]
        if i >= n:
            break
        # find all points not dominated by i
        # since points are sorted by coordinate sum
        # i cannot dominate any points in 1,...,i-1
        undominated[i+1:n] = (pts[i+1:] >= pts[i]).any(1) 
        # keep points undominated so far
        pts = pts[undominated[:n]]
    return pts
```

We start by sorting points according to the sum of coordinates. This is useful because

- For many distributions of data, a point with a largest coordinate sum will dominate a large number of points.
- If point `x` has a larger coordinate sum than point `y`, then `y` cannot dominate `x`.

Here are some benchmarks relative to Peter's answer, using `np.random.randn`.

```
N=10000 d=2

keep_efficient
1.31 ms ± 11.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
is_pareto_efficient
6.51 ms ± 23.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


N=10000 d=3

keep_efficient
2.3 ms ± 13.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
is_pareto_efficient
16.4 ms ± 156 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


N=10000 d=4

keep_efficient
4.37 ms ± 38.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
is_pareto_efficient
21.1 ms ± 115 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


N=10000 d=5

keep_efficient
15.1 ms ± 491 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
is_pareto_efficient
110 ms ± 1.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


N=10000 d=6

keep_efficient
40.1 ms ± 211 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
is_pareto_efficient
279 ms ± 2.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


N=10000 d=15

keep_efficient
3.92 s ± 125 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
is_pareto_efficient
5.88 s ± 74.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

#### Convex Hull Heuristic

I ended up looking at this problem recently and found a useful heuristic that works well if there are many points distributed independently and dimensions are few.

The idea is to compute the convex hull of points. With few dimensions and independently distributed points, the number of vertices of the convex hull will be small. Intuitively, we can expect some vertices of the convex hull to dominate many of the original points. Moreover, if a point in a convex hull is not dominated by any other point in the convex hull, then it is also not dominated by any point in the original set.

This gives a simple iterative algorithm. We repeatedly

1. Compute the convex hull.
2. Save Pareto undominated points from the convex hull.
3. Filter the points to remove those dominated by elements of the convex hull.

I add a few benchmarks for dimension 3. It seems that for some distribution of points this approach yields better asymptotics.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial
from functools import reduce

# test points
pts = np.random.rand(10_000_000, 3)


def filter_(pts, pt):
    """
    Get all points in pts that are not Pareto dominated by the point pt
    """
    weakly_worse   = (pts <= pt).all(axis=-1)
    strictly_worse = (pts < pt).any(axis=-1)
    return pts[~(weakly_worse & strictly_worse)]


def get_pareto_undominated_by(pts1, pts2=None):
    """
    Return all points in pts1 that are not Pareto dominated
    by any points in pts2
    """
    if pts2 is None:
        pts2 = pts1
    return reduce(filter_, pts2, pts1)


def get_pareto_frontier(pts):
    """
    Iteratively filter points based on the convex hull heuristic
    """
    pareto_groups = []

    # loop while there are points remaining
    while pts.shape[0]:
        # brute force if there are few points:
        if pts.shape[0] < 10:
            pareto_groups.append(get_pareto_undominated_by(pts))
            break

        # compute vertices of the convex hull
        hull_vertices = spatial.ConvexHull(pts).vertices

        # get corresponding points
        hull_pts = pts[hull_vertices]

        # get points in pts that are not convex hull vertices
        nonhull_mask = np.ones(pts.shape[0], dtype=bool)
        nonhull_mask[hull_vertices] = False
        pts = pts[nonhull_mask]

        # get points in the convex hull that are on the Pareto frontier
        pareto   = get_pareto_undominated_by(hull_pts)
        pareto_groups.append(pareto)

        # filter remaining points to keep those not dominated by
        # Pareto points of the convex hull
        pts = get_pareto_undominated_by(pts, pareto)

    return np.vstack(pareto_groups)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# previous solutions
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def is_pareto_efficient_dumb(costs):
    """
    :param costs: An (n_points, n_costs) array
    :return: A (n_points, ) boolean array, indicating whether each point is Pareto efficient
    """
    is_efficient = np.ones(costs.shape[0], dtype = bool)
    for i, c in enumerate(costs):
        is_efficient[i] = np.all(np.any(costs>=c, axis=1))
    return is_efficient


def is_pareto_efficient(costs):
    """
    :param costs: An (n_points, n_costs) array
    :return: A (n_points, ) boolean array, indicating whether each point is Pareto efficient
    """
    is_efficient = np.ones(costs.shape[0], dtype = bool)
    for i, c in enumerate(costs):
        if is_efficient[i]:
            is_efficient[is_efficient] = np.any(costs[is_efficient]<=c, axis=1)  # Remove dominated points
    return is_efficient


def dominates(row, rowCandidate):
    return all(r >= rc for r, rc in zip(row, rowCandidate))


def cull(pts, dominates):
    dominated = []
    cleared = []
    remaining = pts
    while remaining:
        candidate = remaining[0]
        new_remaining = []
        for other in remaining[1:]:
            [new_remaining, dominated][dominates(candidate, other)].append(other)
        if not any(dominates(other, candidate) for other in new_remaining):
            cleared.append(candidate)
        else:
            dominated.append(candidate)
        remaining = new_remaining
    return cleared, dominated

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# benchmarking
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# to accomodate the original non-numpy solution
pts_list = [list(pt) for pt in pts]

import timeit

# print('Old non-numpy solution:s\t{}'.format(
    # timeit.timeit('cull(pts_list, dominates)', number=3, globals=globals())))

print('Numpy solution:\t{}'.format(
    timeit.timeit('is_pareto_efficient(pts)', number=3, globals=globals())))

print('Convex hull heuristic:\t{}'.format(
    timeit.timeit('get_pareto_frontier(pts)', number=3, globals=globals())))
```

#### Results

```
# >>= python temp.py # 1,000 points
# Old non-numpy solution:      0.0316428339574486
# Numpy solution:              0.005961259012110531
# Convex hull heuristic:       0.012369581032544374
# >>= python temp.py # 1,000,000 points
# Old non-numpy solution:      70.67529802105855
# Numpy solution:              5.398462114972062
# Convex hull heuristic:       1.5286884519737214
# >>= python temp.py # 10,000,000 points
# Numpy solution:              98.03680767398328
# Convex hull heuristic:       10.203076395904645
```

#### Original Post

I took a shot at rewriting the same algorithm with a couple of tweaks. I think most of your problems come from `inputPoints.remove(row)`. This requires searching through the list of points; removing by index would be much more efficient.
I also modified the `dominates` function to avoid some redundant comparisons. This could be handy in a higher dimension.

```
def dominates(row, rowCandidate):
    return all(r >= rc for r, rc in zip(row, rowCandidate))

def cull(pts, dominates):
    dominated = []
    cleared = []
    remaining = pts
    while remaining:
        candidate = remaining[0]
        new_remaining = []
        for other in remaining[1:]:
            [new_remaining, dominated][dominates(candidate, other)].append(other)
        if not any(dominates(other, candidate) for other in new_remaining):
            cleared.append(candidate)
        else:
            dominated.append(candidate)
        remaining = new_remaining
    return cleared, dominated
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying right now. Any idea how it would compare to the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294829/fast-calculations-of-the-pareto-front-in-r ?

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It would also be nice to know how to choose the best point in the set of points returned as the Pareto frontier. Also, there may be some objectives that need to be minimized and some need to be maximized and some need to kept constant.

Comment: @Nav I am not sure I follow your suggestion entirely. For every point in the Pareto frontier it is possible to write down an objective function s.t. that point is "the best". Are you thinking about multi-objective optimization? This is not something I had in mind for this answer.

Comment: Yes; multiobjective optimization. I eventually realized I could just use your function and then calculate the centroid of the Pareto optimal points using K-Means to find the approx. "best" point. Also, since `min(f(x)) = - max(-f(x))`, I could use your function unchanged and simply negate the columns of numbers that I want to minimize.

Comment: Makes sense. My experience with multi-objective optimization is mostly in bilevel programming, but I would imagine that there are more efficient methods not based on this approach.

Comment: The code from Update Aug 2019 looks to be not working properly - the returned set is not the efficient frontier. For example for this set (https://gist.github.com/vfilimonov/4e368a7a6235ae2aff8e9c47a569e974) many points from pareto frontier are missing

Comment: @Vladimir good catch. It looks like the problem had to do with the strict inequality when testing for undominated points. This causes a bug when two points have the same value of some coordinate, as in your example. Note that the updated output of `is_pareto_efficient` and `keep_efficient` will not be the same because the point `[4.8, 4.8]` appears twice and my code does not handle duplicates.

Comment: Adding the comparison with visuals: https://github.com/Gricel-lee/Pareto/blob/main/ParetoFunction.ipynb   It seems to be getting the weak non-dominated solutions. Still very useful

Answer (score 4):

Peter, nice response.

I just wanted to generalise for those who want to choose between maximisation to your default of minimisation. It's a trivial fix, but nice to document here:

```
def is_pareto(costs, maximise=False):
    """
    :param costs: An (n_points, n_costs) array
    :maximise: boolean. True for maximising, False for minimising
    :return: A (n_points, ) boolean array, indicating whether each point is Pareto efficient
    """
    is_efficient = np.ones(costs.shape[0], dtype = bool)
    for i, c in enumerate(costs):
        if is_efficient[i]:
            if maximise:
                is_efficient[is_efficient] = np.any(costs[is_efficient]>=c, axis=1)  # Remove dominated points
            else:
                is_efficient[is_efficient] = np.any(costs[is_efficient]<=c, axis=1)  # Remove dominated points
    return is_efficient
```

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `dominates` is incorrect. A dominates B if and only if it is better than or equal to B on all dimensions, and strictly better on at least one dimension.

Answer (score 2):

I might be a little late here but I experimented with the proposed solutions and it seems that they are failing to return all the Pareto points. I have made a recursive implementation (which is significantly faster) to find the Pareto-front and you can find it at https://github.com/Ragheb2464/preto-front

Comment: Please provide a counter-example

Comment: Nice! Your solution worked for me, all the others didn't  (i don't know how to retrieve the costs array)

Answer (score 1):

Correcting an error found in a previous post, here is a new version of the keep_efficient function.

```
def keep_efficient(pts):
    'returns Pareto efficient row subset of pts'
    # sort points by decreasing sum of coordinates
    pts = pts[pts.sum(1).argsort()[::-1]]
    # initialize a boolean mask for undominated points
    # to avoid creating copies each iteration
    undominated = np.ones(pts.shape[0], dtype=bool)
    for i in range(pts.shape[0]):
        # process each point in turn
        n = pts.shape[0]
        if i >= n:
            break
        # find all points not dominated by i
        # since points are sorted by coordinate sum
        # i cannot dominate any points in 1,...,i-1
        undominated[i+1:n] = (pts[i+1:] >= pts[i]).any(1) 
        # keep points undominated so far
        pts = pts[undominated[:n]]
        undominated = np.array([True]*len(pts))

return pts
```

(Note that the error in the previous post was that the function keep_efficient(pts) returned a wrong Pareto front with inputs: pts = [[5,5],[4,3], [0,6]]. Before the edit, the result was [5,5] while the expected result is [[5 5], [0 6]]. The fix was to add the last line of the for loop: undominated = np.array([True]*len(pts)))

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear for the example above, the function to get the Pareto-front is slightly different then in the code above and should include only a < not a <= looking like this:

```
def is_pareto(costs):
    is_efficient = np.ones(costs.shape[0], dtype=bool)

    for i, c in enumerate(is_efficient):
        if is_efficient[i]:
           is_efficient[is_efficient] = np.any(costs[is_efficient]<c, axis=1) 

    return is_efficient
```

Disclaimer: This is only partial correct because domination itself is defined as <= for all and only < for at least one. But for most cases it should be sufficient