# Optimize Pareto front filtering in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying (again: [Fast calculation of Pareto front in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791911/fast-calculation-of-pareto-front-in-python)) to filter a list of lists to only keep only the non-dominated set.

I put together a script which finally works for me:

```
import operator
import copy
import time
import random

def select_dominated(a,b):
    ge = all(map(operator.ge, a, b))
    le = all(map(operator.le, a, b))
    # return dominated
    return b if ge else a if le else 'indifferent'

def paretoFront(a):
    b = copy.deepcopy(a)
    if len(a) > 1:
        for i in range(len(a)):
            for j in range(i,len(a)):
                if i != j:
                    try:
                        b.remove(select_dominated(a[i],a[j]))
                    except:
                        ""
    return b

set = []
for i in range(1000):
    set.append([random.random(),random.random(),random.random()])

t0 = time.time()
print len(set),"->",len(paretoFront(set)),"in",time.time()-t0,"seconds"
```

Expect, for large lists, it's pretty slow (3 sec. to filter 1000 3d points).
I heard "remove" is pretty slow. How would I go about optimizing this code?

Comment: See answer to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40239615/851699

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I'm not well-versed in what a Pareto front is, so I'm deducing what the code is based on what you've provided.)

Because this is in pure Python (i.e. no external libraries used), most of the time will be spent on the iteration (your `for` loops).

There's two strategies I'd suggest.

Firstly, see if your code is vectorizable. For example, you may want to represent your data as a `numpy` array. Shamelessly copying code from [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578287-multidimensional-pareto-front/), you may want to do:

```
def pareto_frontier_multi(myArray):
    # Sort on first dimension
    myArray = myArray[myArray[:,0].argsort()]
    # Add first row to pareto_frontier
    pareto_frontier = myArray[0:1,:]
    # Test next row against the last row in pareto_frontier
    for row in myArray[1:,:]:
        if sum([row[x] >= pareto_frontier[-1][x]
                for x in range(len(row))]) == len(row):
            # If it is better on all features add the row to pareto_frontier
            pareto_frontier = np.concatenate((pareto_frontier, [row]))
    return pareto_frontier

my_array = np.random.random((3, 1000))
pareto_frontier_multi(my_array)
```

`numpy` uses vectorization to give speedups.

Secondly, if you want to stick with pure Python, then you can try out PyPy. Download the PyPy executable binaries, have your bash terminal recognize where they are located (by editing the bash shell `PATH` variable), and then execute your code under PyPy. I have written a [blog post](http://www.ericmajinglong.com/2015/11/28/profiling-pypy-vs-python-for-agent-based-simulation-2/) that can show you the speedups in PyPy. Essentially, without the overhead of type checking each iteration, your loops will run much faster. It's almost like having vectorization, though they're not the same.

Comment: Thanks @ericmjl strangly, this algorithm doesn't give me the same results as mine (I'm pretty sure mine provides correct results)... I'll keep on trying

Comment: @Rodolphe: yes, I would trust your algorithm. :) I will admit, I didn't check the algorithm against your results, so yes, I would trust your implementation over what I've linked. Keep pushing on it!

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this:

```
import time
import random
from functools import reduce

def paretoFront(data):
    def select_dominant(criterions_left, criterions_right, strict=True):
        op = operator.gt if strict else operator.ge
        for criterion_left, criterion_right in zip(criterions_left, criterions_right):
            if op(criterion_left, criterion_right):
                continue
            else:
                if not strict and criterion_left == criterion_right:
                    continue
                else:
                    break
        else:
            return criterions_left
        
        return criterions_right
    
    dominant = reduce(select_dominant, data[1:], data[0])
    return [row for row in data if select_dominant(row, dominant, strict=False) == row]

data = []
for i in range(1000):
    data.append(
        [
            random.random(),
            random.random(),
            random.random()
        ]
    )

time_start = time.perf_counter()
selected_values = paretoFront(data)
time_stop = time.perf_counter()

print(f'{len(data)} -> {len(selected_values)} in {time_stop - time_start} sec')
```