# How to find lists that are dominated (for all possible indexes if list1[index] <= list2[index], list1 is dominated) in a set of lists in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists, namely `L` which contains `N` lists. And, those lists only contain integers and they have the same length.

For any list `P`, if there is a list in `L` other than `P` itself (Let's call it *H*) such that for all *i* in range(0, len(*P*)) *P[i]* <= *H[i]* holds, let's call P *dominated*.

I need to find all lists in `L` that are dominated, but I need something more efficient than checking them in pairs. That would require *N* * *(N-1)* / *2* iterations, considering *N* I am using is pretty big, that would not be fast enough for me.

Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: How does the list length compare to `N`?

Comment: @Prune N is about 500,000 and len(L[0]) is 5

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I believe this is the same question as you are asking? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791911/fast-calculation-of-pareto-front-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fast calculation of Pareto front in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791911/fast-calculation-of-pareto-front-in-python)

Comment: @KevinWang Yes, thank you very much! Checking it as pareto front never came into my mind, sorry for the repost.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the list L based on 0th element of each inner list P, and iteratively `for i in range(1, len(P))`, and eliminate each inner list H if it doesn't dominate the list before it. This I hope might drop most of the offending lists quickly. Theoretical this is still O(N x len(P)), but the N lists should drop quickly to a smaller number.

this should have rather been a comment I guess...