# Choosing optimal pairs from list

Tags: python, optimization, plot

I have a code that calculates random pairs (volatility vs expected returns; for an efficient frontier) and puts them into a list. Is there any way to narrow the list down to only "efficient pairs" (hence, the maximum return for each volatility)? So there would only be a line at the top (like in the picture)?

[image]

Also connecting the dots with a line would go a long way!

ff is a pandas Dataframe with daily returns (floats)
Code:

```
    Mean = ff.mean()
    Vol = ff.cov()
    nPort = 10000
    weight = np.zeros((nPort,11))
    eR = np.zeros((nPort,11))
    eV = np.zeros((nPort,11))
    sR = np.zeros((nPort,11))
    for k in range(nPort):
        # generate random weight vector
        w = np.array(np.random.random(11))
        w = w/np.sum(w)
        weight[k,:] = w
        # expected returns
        eR[k] = np.sum(Mean * w)
        # expected Vol
        eV[k] = np.sqrt(np.dot(w.T,np.dot(Vol,w)))
        #sharpe
        sR[k] = eR[k]/eV[k]
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
    plt.scatter(eV,eR, c=sR)
    plt.colorbar(label='sR')

    plt.show()
```

Comment: you already have the points connected with a line.

Comment: I drew that with snipping tool.

Comment: there is insufficient data in the question to provide a complete answer, but you could sample the `x-axis` of the data, finding local maxima (or average maxima) and connect these...

Comment: What data would be needed to answer the question? @D.L

Comment: generally speaking this it what helps users assist: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You are looking for the Pareto Front of these points.  This may answer your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791911/fast-calculation-of-pareto-front-in-python

Comment: This link has what appears to be decent code that calculates pareto front for 2-D problems:  https://oco-carbon.com/metrics/find-pareto-frontiers-in-python/